# Why was my answer to the question " Does the New Testament use the divine name “Yahweh”?" deleted?

Tags: discussion

Here is the link to the question I answered.
[enter link description here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7454/does-the-new-testament-use-the-divine-name-yahweh/47173?noredirect=1#comment92697_47173)

Answer (score 2):

I commented on there - your answer consists of a long quote from somewhere else, most of which doesn't directly touch on the OP's question. I asked you to edit it to the portion that does (I read through about half without finding anything), and then flag for it to be undeleted.

Comment: Can you specify the half that you think should be deleted?

Comment: I had 2 answers  to the same question, My first answer was 8 paragraphs long, compared to the the others, which were 30 + paragraphs. Can you please consider undeleting my 1st answer?

Comment: I did not read your whole answer, but as an example, the paragraphs on "How Does Jehovah Feel?" don't address the question of "Does the NT use the divine name Yahweh?"

Comment: Your other answer has a comment from you saying "This is not an answer to the question." Maybe I'm not understanding, but if something isn't an answer, then it's not permitted in the answer space.

Comment: @Soldamai. I'm sorry. I posted that from the site that I found it without redacting it.If there is any more part of my second answer that you think should be deleted, please inform me and I will delete them?  About my 1st answer, can you please consider undeleting it?

Comment: @Soldamai The "This is not an answer to the question" comment from me was a reply to 
 Walter Spetna's comment..